# PowerShell Command for reset Computer in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I search for a command which is the equivalent of the button in the screenshot:

[image]

I already found the command [Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378946%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) but this command is only usable for the local computer.

[Reset-QADComputer](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Reset-QADComputer) is a solution, but I want to try it with the Active Directory Module from Powershell, not from a third party company.

Is there a way to reset a Computer in the Active Directory with the Active Directory Module from Powershell ?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: I don't think so, because it is a programming relevant question @Mgetz

Comment: Not really. It's basically a systems management automation question, so SF would indeed be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Powershell is a programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) and this is a question for a specific command in this programming language. I think, that SO is the right Q&A site.@AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`dsmod`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753596.aspx):

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity "computername" | % {
  dsmod computer $_.distinguishedName -reset
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, I'll give a try on monday and will responce and accept then.
It's weekend *yes*